# How to group images in iWork Pages?

Tags: pages, iwork

How to group multiple images in iWork Pages so I don't have to move images one by one? That can be done in Microsoft Words, but I can't find this option in iWork Pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cmd-Click to select the images you want to group and then opt-cmd-G to group them (find the group function under the ARRANGE menu), then the images will move as one unit. To ungroup the images shift-opt-cmd-G.

Comment: Good first answer, and welcome, by the way :)